# MS Web Deploy Ignoring <setParameter> Entries + Writing to wrong file

Tags: jenkins, msdeploy, webdeploy

## Problem

1. We have 3 parameters required to authenticate with our 3rd party service: username, password, securityToken which live in unexpected places (depending on environment they could be in Web.config or CI build scripts).
2. We're asking MS Web Deploy to write `<setParameter>` values from our XML files but it's ignoring some... specifically the username, password and security token parameters
3. MS Web Deploy wants to write to `\Views\Web.config`.  We want to write to `\Web.config`.

## 2 Goals

1. Organize all of our authentication credentials in to `DeploySettings.xml` files respective to each or our environments (dev, qa and production).
2. Write `<setParameter>` values to **\Web.config** not **\Views\Web.config**

## Details

- We're uisng Jenkins for continuous integration.
- Jenkins is calling MS Web Deploy 3 to handle the deployment.
- We're going to have a **DeploySettings** file for each environment.
- I'm currently working on our dev environment.  For the scope of this question, I'll be referring to our "dev" environment and it's respective `DeploySettings.Dev.xml` file
- The Jenkins deploy script tells web deploy to use `-setParamFile` to overwrite \Web.config values with `<setParameter>` values from the `DeploySettings.Dev.xml` file

#### Deploy Script calling for DeploySettings file

```
-setParamFile:"%WORKSPACE%\DeploySettings.Dev.xml" -verbose
```

#### DeploySettings.Dev.xml

> ⚠️ *This is not the entire file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter 
    name="username" 
    value="lukeSkywalker" />
  <setParameter 
    name="password" 
    value="xxxxxx" />
  <setParameter 
    name="token" 
    value="xxxxxx" />
  <setParameter 
    name="DBConnection" 
    value="Data Source=fully.qulified.domain;Initial Catalog=CatalogName;uid=obiwan;password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  <setParameter 
    name="SessionDBConnection" 
    value="Data Source=1.2.3.4;uid=userId;password=xxxxxx" />
...
```

#### Verbose Jenkins Deployment console logging demonstrating that username, password and token are being ignored

> *note that `username`, `password` and `token` are absent*

```
Verbose: Parameter entry 'DBConnection/1' is applicable to '\Web.config' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'SessionDBConnection/1' is applicable to '\Web.config' because of its scope.
```

#### Verbose Jenkins Deployment console logging showing that we're writing to the wrong file (\Views\Web.config)

```
Verbose: Parameter entry 'DBConnection/1' is applicable to '\Views\Web.config' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'DBConnection/1' could not be applied to '\Views\Web.config'. Deployment will continue with the original data. Details:

Verbose: Parameter entry 'DBConnection/1' is applicable to '\Views\Web.config' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'DBConnection/1' could not be applied to '\Views\Web.config'. Deployment will continue with the original data. Details:
```

## Burning Questions

- How do I configure Web Deploy to write to \Web.config?  \Views\Web.config is wrong
- How to configure `-setParamFile` to fetch and overwrite `username`, `password` and `token`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Heinrich I forgot about this one!  I posted my solution, please see below.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem Solved

I moved this type of config-rewrite work in to the build script (Jenkins > "Your Project " > Build > Configure).

Here's an example of how I got it to work

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:dirPath="%WORKSPACE%\" ^
  -dest:package="%WORKSPACE%\ArtifactName-%BUILD_NUMBER%.zip" ^
  -replace:objectName=dirPath,targetAttributeName=path,match="^C:\\.*\\pathToSite",replace="c:\sitesRoot\pathToSite" ^
  -declareParam:name=DBConnection,kind=XmlFile,scope=Web.config,match=//configuration/connectionStrings/add/@connectionString,defaultValue="Data Source=1.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=dbName;uid=website;password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" ^
  -declareParam:name=SessionDBConnection,kind=XmlFile,scope=Web.config,match=//configuration/system.web/sessionState/@sqlConnectionString,defaultValue="Data Source=1.2.3.4;uid=xxxx;password=xxxx" ^
  -declareParam:name=Parameter1,kind=XmlFile,scope=Web.config,match=//configuration/appSettings/add[@key="Parameter1"]/@value,defaultValue="paramValue1" ^
  -declareParam:name=Paramtere2,kind=XmlFile,scope=Web.config,match=//configuration/appSettings/add[@key="Parameter2"]/@value,defaultValue="paramvalue2" ^
```